# How to add custom list value to display as chip view in android?

Tags: android

```
public class ChipsView extends TokenCompleteTextView<ContactList> {

    public ChipsView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public ChipsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ChipsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected View getViewForObject(ContactList list) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chip,(ViewGroup)getParent(), false);
        TextView chip =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chipsview);
        TextView label = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);

        chip.setText(list.getName());
        label.setText(list.getLabel());

    return view;
    }
}
```

Here I could add only the values in list as chip view ? how can I add new values to display it as chip view?

Comment: Can you show UI or something to show the end result?

Comment: <ChipsView
    android:hint="@string/share_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    />